# Adding tiles image background to flutter Textfield

Tags: flutter, background-image, textfield

What is the best way to add a tiled background to a TextField in flutter. I need the tile images to scroll with the text if the text content gets large enough, this means I can't just use a stack and put an images behind the textfield.  Only way I can think of how i can achieve this is to use a scrollview inside a stack behind the textfield and somehow synchronize the scroll between the two widgets. But this feels really complicated for such a simple thing. What am I missing here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Container with DecorationImage ( to set your image ) and it's child : TextField( ..)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try this. But i have doubts that this is going to make the background scrollable with the texts in the textfield.

Comment: If you can provide a video or image for explaining what you need carefully